# PayPal Donation - Transaction Details

Tags: php, paypal, transactions

Here is my issue:

I'm building a website for a Non-For Profit Organization that seeks to "Market" (give publicity) other NFPOs so that they can get more donations.  Their focus has always been on providing workshops for better financial management.

The website is almost ready and PayPal Donation buttons work.  However, since the NFPO NEEDS to generate reports regarding the donations made to EACH NFPO in their listing, I need to retrieve the details of the transaction to save them in a DB.  I need the following fields:

1. Amount
2. Donor e-mail
3. Donor Name
4. Transaction Date
5. Organization ID (Instead of providing a Product ID, I will be passing the Organization's ID #, if possible, to PayPal.)

I've been reading about the Payment Data Transfer (Classic API) however, I would have to 'set up' a paypal account to be able to get this info.

Problems:

1. There will be many PayPal addresses (Donations will be made directly to each NFPO for transparency purposes)
2. As such, there's no way for us to set up every participant Organization's account to work with it.
3. Checking the instructions in (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/), I see it doesn't even match with the new layout of the webpage.  So, it is very difficult to even implement a tutorial for them to do it.

Is there any way transaction information can be requested from the API without setup?

Thanks for your time and responses.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) and [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) should give you everything you need.